# Enqueue multiple jobs in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I would like to know if there is a way to enqueue multiple jobs in ActiveJob?
Similar to the sidekiq push_bulk.

```
Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk(sidekiq_items)
```

I need to enqueue thousands of jobs and it takes too much time to do it one by one.

Comment: Did you try to enqueue them in a loop and measure the time that took?

Comment: No - but it takes several minutes when I am queueing 100k jobs. I am supposed to queue > 1M jobs at a time. Probably the solution is to create a Job for queueing the Jobs :).

Comment: Sounds like you need to skip the built-in simple solution and use something with better features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.  ActiveJob does not have an abstraction for every Sidekiq feature.

Comment: Hi Mike! I see what you did here ;) but I went back to use sidekiq directly.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 7 there still isn't a way built into ActiveJob to accomplish this, but it's pretty easy to roll your own. (And it's a testament to the quality and endurance of Sidekiq that this question is still relevant 8 years later!)

```ruby
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def self.perform_later_bulk(array_of_args)
    sidekiq_args = array_of_args.map { |args| [new(*args).serialize] }

    Sidekiq::Client.push_bulk(
      'class' => ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper,
      'wrapped' => self,
      'queue' => sidekiq_args[0][0]['queue_name'],
      'args' => sidekiq_args
    )
  end
end

def SomeJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(arg1, arg2)
    # etc
  end
end

# Usage: SomeJob.perform_later_bulk([[arg1, arg2], [arg1, arg2], ...])
```

Tested on Rails 7, but it should work at least as far back as 5.2.